# Tensorflow OD API - Use of dropout when fine-tuning a model

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, dropout, mobilenet

I'm trying to fine-tune the SSD MobileNet v2 (from the model zoo) with my own data. In pipeline.config I see that `use_dropout` is set to false. Why is that? I thought dropout should be used to prevent overfitting.

```
box_predictor {
  convolutional_box_predictor {
    conv_hyperparams {
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 3.99999989895e-05
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          mean: 0.0
          stddev: 0.0299999993294
        }
      }
      activation: RELU_6
      batch_norm {
        decay: 0.999700009823
        center: true
        scale: true
        epsilon: 0.0010000000475
        train: true
      }
    }
    min_depth: 0
    max_depth: 0
    num_layers_before_predictor: 0
    use_dropout: false
    dropout_keep_probability: 0.800000011921
    kernel_size: 3
    box_code_size: 4
    apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
  }
}
```

Is it because of batch normalization? In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf), it says that:

> 3.4 Batch Normalization regularizes the
>   model
>
> When training with Batch Normalization, a training example is seen in conjunction with other examples in the
>   mini-batch, and the training network no longer producing deterministic values for a given training example. In
>   our experiments, we found this effect to be advantageous
>   to the generalization of the network. Whereas Dropout
>   (Srivastava et al., 2014) is typically used to reduce overfitting, in a batch-normalized network we found that it can
>   be either removed or reduced in strength.

Comment: What happens when you change dropout to true? Did you test it, did it work?